# No se muestran las vistas relacionadas al Auth en Laravel al usar Xampp

Tags: laravel

Al habilitar el Auth en mi proyecto con la siguiente linea de comandos

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

funciona de maravilla se instalan los paquetes, se crean las carpetas Auth todo bien

el problema es que cuando en el navegador utilizando Xampp veo mi proyecto cuando hago click a la vista del Login o de Registro me devuelve el error 404

En web.php esta la ruta:

```
Auth::routes();
```

Si utilizo el comando `php artisan serve` las vistas de login y registro se muestran sin problemas

¿Cual es el problema para cuando uso solo Xampp me devuelva el error 404?

Comment: ¿En XAMPP usas virtual hosts?

Comment: levanto Apache y Mysql

Comment: Asegurate de habilitar mod_rewrite en  apache. Dale una mirada a esta parte de la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#apache